# Element won't respond to height set as percentage even though parent has set height

Tags: html, css

I have been puzzling over this bit of HTML/CSS for hours and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. It is part of a more complicated layout, but I think I have isolated the problem.

This is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class = "outer">
                <div class = "middle">
                    <div class = "inner">
                        <svg viewbox = "0, 0, 250, 250">
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...and this is my CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;      
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; 
}
table {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    /*table-layout: fixed;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

tr {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 190px);
}

td {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
}

.outer {
    width: 94%;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 94%;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    margin: 3%;
    margin: calc(10px + 0%);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.middle {
    display: white;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: calc(100%  - 10px - 2.5rem);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner {
    background-color: pink;
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: salmon;
}
```

If you remove the SVG, the divs and table behave as I would like - on window resize, the table doesn't exceed the size of the page, and the divs all scale accordingly.

When you include the svg, what I would expect (and what I would want) is for the svg to scale to fit the .inner div, but not to exceed it or alter the flow of the layout in any way.
This is not what happens.

I've checked this in Safari and in Firefox, and both give me unexpected but different results. In firefox, if the window shrinks beyond a certain point, the svg height expands and the whole window ends up scrolling.

In Safari, the svg height scales as the width changes, but the width doesn't scale as the height changes.

This seems like a pretty simple thing and I don't really know where I'm going wrong. I am sure it is an obvious rookie error of some sort. I have tried every combination of max/min height/width on the svg.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: If I get rid of the table (remove the table, td, tr) everything works as expected. Equally, if I get rid of the svg and keep the table, everything works as expected.

Comment: _“If I get rid of the table […]”_ – do you have actual tabular data to display here? If not, you should get rid of the table for that reason alone already …

Comment: The larger layout this is part of does need the table as I need the entire content to be split into rows with vertical centering on the contents and take up 100% of the screen height. I've tried doing this with just divs and ran into a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

As [stated here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#DataTypeLength), you can't set a width/height value of `auto` for an svg element. Use `100%` for the height and width instead like this:

```
svg {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: salmon;
}
```

If the problem still persist, try adding the `height` and `width` property as an inline style declaration to the svg and see if that fixes the problem:

```
<svg style="width:100% max-width:100%; height: 100%; max-height: 100%;" viewbox = "0, 0, 250, 250"></svg>
```

Comment: That doesn't work I'm afraid! I get xactly the same result. The main thing I don't understand is how this seems to be effected by window resize - at some window sizes it behaves correctly, and at others it seems like it can't set height by %.

Comment: ...More to the point: at some window sizes it treats 100% height as if it is referring to the height of the parent, and at others as if it's referring to the height of the parent's parent, and at others as if it as no ancestor with a set height.

Comment: @Martha Can you please give me a link to the site you're implementing the svg on?

Answer (score 0):

you missed to give height on `tbody`

```
tbody {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Actually browser automatically add tbody in your table if you not add. you can see this in inspect element